# Docusign Integration with Microsoft Teams

Tags: reactjs, docusignapi, microsoft-teams

I want to send a document from a react Teams app to Docusign for Signature. Has anyone come accross the same?

Answer (score 0):

You could use out of the box [DocuSign Teams integrations](https://www.docusign.com/blog/esignature-microsoft-teams).

You could use something like [Zapier](https://zapier.com/apps/docusign/integrations/microsoft-teams?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=gaw-usa-nua-performancemax-202110_usa_cpa&utm_adgroup=&utm_term=&utm_content=_pcrid__pkw__pmt__pdv_c_slid__pgrid__ptaid__&gclid=CjwKCAjw7IeUBhBbEiwADhiEMUa1xa9g3ybk8kgWaW08ISKtyn50Mgyd-zHZjoU8qy_Xz4snY90MpBoCTBwQAvD_BwE) that can connect many things together with APIs.

You could write your own if you want.

Comment: @Vinita - Could you please confirm is your issue resolved? or are you still looking for any help?